# Ceiling fan extra pair of wire for light

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I have two power switches in my study which go to the ceiling fan. The ceiling fan is a fan+light combo and uses only one pair of wires. The other switch is unused. The light from the fan is not sufficient for room, and I do not particularly like the idea of floor lamps. I am looking for ideas on ways to run track for lights that is aesthetically pleasing. I would appreciate some pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking about aesthetically pleasing is more personal design likes so not allowed here.  Asking how to wire the track lights up will be.  You seem to have an unused switch and wires in the ceiling, so half the work should be done already.